# Как менять параметры выделенного текста в JTextPane?

Tags: java, алгоритм, swing

Допустим, в `JTextPane` есть строка произвольного содержания и длины.

Пользователь выделяет в ней символы, начиная с символа с индексом `*` по символ с индексом `**`

Как узнать эти два индекса? Нужно для изменения цвета выделенного текста через `setCharacterAttributes()`

Пример: `Строка "12345 12"` Я выделил символы с `'3' по '5'` то есть, начиная с символа с индексом `2` по символ с индексом `4` как это узнать программно?

Comment: Если честно, не особо понял. То есть в JTextPane выводится текст, затем ты выделяя этот текст с символа * до ** и нажав например ПКМ поменять параметры, например цвет, прямо в JTextPane?

Comment: @ArturVartanyan Мне нужно поменять цвет именно выделенного текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел [ответ на англоязычном StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163071/apply-color-for-selected-text-using-jtextpane) Попробую перевести.

> Если хотите установить свой стиль только для абзаца или какого-то
>   определенного символа, используйте
>
> ```
> StyledDocument.setParagraphAttributes(offset, length, s, replace);
> ```
>
> или
>
> ```
> StyledDocument.setCharacterAttributes(offset, length, s, replace);
> ```
>
> Вот так:
>
> ```
>   private void SetTextColorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
>
>     Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(this, "Colors",Color.BLUE);
>     StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
>     int from = textPane.getSelectionStart();
>     int to = textPane.getSelectionEnd();
>     Style style = textPane.addStyle("I'm a Style", null);
>     StyleConstants.setForeground(style, color);
>     doc.setCharacterAttributes(from, to-from, style, true);
> }
> ```

Мой код изменения цвета текста:

```
 private StyledDocument document;
 private Color textColor = Color.BLACK;
 private  JColorChooser colorChooser;

  // Показываем пользователю диалог выбора цвета
 private void showColorChooser(){
    colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
    if (textColor==null){ textColor = Color.BLACK;}
    textColor =  colorChooser.showDialog(null,"Цвет текста", textColor);
    colorChoseButton.setBackground(textColor);
    colorChoseButton.setForeground(textColor);
    if(textArea.getSelectedText()==null){
        textArea.setForeground(textColor);

    }
}
   // меняем цвет текста
private void changeTextColor(Color c, String str){
    document = textArea.getStyledDocument();

    SimpleAttributeSet colorSeter = new SimpleAttributeSet();

    StyleConstants.setForeground(colorSeter, c);
    document.setCharacterAttributes(textArea.getSelectionStart(), textArea.getSelectionEnd()-textArea.getSelectionStart(),colorSeter,true);
     textColor = colorChoseButton.getBackground();
     textArea.setSelectedTextColor(textColor);
}

       @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Если нажали на кнопку выбора цвета или на соответствующий пункт меню — вызываем два метода
if (e.getSource()==colorChoseButton || e.getSource()==getJMenuBar().getMenu(2).getItem(2)){
        this.showColorChooser();
        this.changeTextColor(textColor, textArea.getSelectedText());
    }
    };
```

Получить первый и последний символы выделения можно методами:

```
JTextPane.getSelectionStart();
```

и

```
JTextPane.getSelectionEnd();
```

А цвет всего выделенного текста меняется строкой

```
    StyleDocument.setCharacterAttributes(JTextPane.getSelectionStart(), JTextPane.getSelectionEnd()-JTextPane.getSelectionStart(),SimpleAttributeSet,true);
```

Вместо `StyleDocument, JTextPane и SimpleAttributeSet` поставьте имена ваших объектов.